# Wordpress Search not picking up text provided by a Plugin

Tags: search

I have a site plugin that fills in text on pages remotely. Wordpress does not search the pages created by the plugin. I tried Google custom search engine code, no good. How can I search this text? Also how can I show search snippets not entire posts listed out? Site is at www.SiteNamePro.com. The domains listed are filled in by the plugin. I want users to find domain names by search, not using CTRL+F, just using normal Wordpress search, or by what appears to them to be normal WP search. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried to do in order to get this to work? What code are you using? Or what code has been changed?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress searches the columns `post_title` and `post_content`. If you add your content to these columns they are searched. If you add the extra content per filter or shortcode during output you need a search plugin that is capable of indexing rendered pages ([Relevanssi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/relevanssi/) or [Search Everything](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-everything/) for example).